# Processing nodes, xml to xlst

Tags: xml, xslt

After gutting this over and over trying to figure out here is all that is left of my xlst.
I am trying to pull the child elements from the xml document and out put them but even with a well formed document I am some how getting a parsing error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

      <xsl:output method="text"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="FamousMountains/mountain"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>

      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Note: This is a comment-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Asg06.xsl"?>
<FamousMountains>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Everest</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa verestEa</name>
    <location>Nepal</location>
    <height units="feet">29035</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Ranier</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">14411</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount St. Helens</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">8364</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Washington</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa ashingtonWa</name>
    <location>New Hampshire</location>
    <height units="feet">6288</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Bonnell</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa onnellBa</name>
    <location>Austin</location>
    <height units="feet">800</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Vesuvius</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa esuviusVa</name>
    <location>Italy</location>
    <height units="feet">4203</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Etna</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa tnaEa</name>
    <location>Sicily</location>
    <height units="feet">10922</height>
  </mountain>
</FamousMountains>
```

This is what the xlst should output:

```
Put your name here
Famous Mountains of the World

Mountain Name: Mount Everest
Mountain Name: (ountMa verestEa)

Mountain Name: Mount Ranier
Mountain Name: ()

Mountain Name: Mount St. Helens
Mountain Name: ()

Mountain Name: Mount Washington
Mountain Name: (ountMa ashingtonWa)

Mountain Name: Mount Bonnell
Mountain Name: (ountMa onnellBa)

Mountain Name: Mount Vesuvius
Mountain Name: (ountMa esuviusVa)

Mountain Name: Mount Etna
Mountain Name: (ountMa tnaEa)
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that your actual stylesheet? It's missing some parts. It wouldn't work like that.

Comment: Put the value-of inside the for-each: `<xsl:for-each ...> <xsl:value-of...> </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: the xlst is where i finally just deleted my mess and left it gutted the xml is from the assignment and works fine on my end.

Comment: It was badly formatted, so the code didn't show up. Always check if your code formatted correctly.

Comment: Yea, sorry its a learning process for me at the moment. Thanks for the formatting.

Comment: Well, you can start by looking at some examples on how `<xsl:for-each>` works. See what I wrote above. You'll probably also need `<xsl:text>` to print the text you want, spaces and line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate what the comments say (@helderdarocha), the `<xsl:value-of />` will only work if it's inside the `<xsl:for-each />` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="FamousMountains/mountain" >
            <xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Gives**

```
Mount EverestMount RanierMount St. HelensMount WashingtonMount BonnellMount VesuviusMount Etna
```

This should be enough to get you started! (but here's an answer anyway.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">Put your name here
Famous Mountains of the World<xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mountain">
Mountain Name: <xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>
Mountain Name: (<xsl:value-of select="name[@language='PigLatin'] "/>)</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you I was having a heard time figuring out where I was messing it up.

Comment: Ha, no problem. I heard that too. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity if any one knows, how do you remove the white space between the the output if I wanted?

Comment: Simply change the `<xsl:apply-templates />` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="//mountain" />`. Btw, feel free to hit the tick next to the answer, if it has answered your question! ;)